# restore database using impdp full back

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g, impdp

1. I have new server and i installed oracle 10g same like production. and I have databump full backup using sys user. I need to restore on the new server.
2. I used the following command while database is not mounted but asks for directory parameter.

Code:

```
impdp full=y direcotry=/home/oracle/rmanscripts/dumbbackup dumpfile=sysfull.dmp logfile=full_db.log.
```

please share me the steps to restore the database to a new server!

Answer (score 3):

Data Pump uses directory objects. Read this:

[Default Locations for Dump, Log, and SQL Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#i1009520)

First create the directory object as:

```
create directory dump_dir as '/home/oracle/rmanscripts/dumbbackup';
```

Then you can use that in your impdp command:

```
impdp full=y direcotry=dump_dir dumpfile=sysfull.dmp logfile=full_db.log
```

Also:

> while database is not mounted

By this I hope you mean it is open. Data Pump needs a working database, even if it is empty.

Comment: `direcotry` :-)